# Can I use a single instance of a delegate to start multiple Asynchronous Requests?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, iasyncresult

Just wondered if someone could clarify the use of `BeginInvoke` on an instance of some delegate when you want to make multiple asynchronous calls since the MSDN documentation doesn't really cover/mention this at all.

What I want to do is something like the following:

```
MyDelegate d = new MyDelegate(this.TargetMethod);
List<IAsyncResult> results = new List<IAsyncResult>();

//Start multiple asynchronous calls
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   results.Add(d.BeginInvoke(someParams, null, null));
}

//Wait for all my calls to finish
WaitHandle.WaitAll(results.Select(r => r.AsyncWaitHandle).ToArray());

//Process the Results
```

The question is can I do this with one instance of the delegate or do I need an instance of the delegate for each individual call?

Given that `EndInvoke()` takes an `IAsyncResult` as a parameter I would assume that the former is correct but I can't see anything in the documentation to indicate either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  You'll get a different IAsyncResult for each call to BeginInvoke().  There's no state associated with the started thread in the delegate object itself.